Error message on importing SSIS project into MS Visual Studio
I got the following error message on importing SQL SSIS project into MS Visual Studio. It was working fine previously since I need to do the project modifications frequently and it stopped working from yesterday.By the way, we have SQL server 2016 and Visual Studio 2017. Can someone assist me ?

Thank you very much !
I would like to see the SSIS package import successfully in VS

The error is reporting a memory issue.  Could you check on available memory, shut down browser windows and other applications while you try to perform the operation?

Mark, Thank you for your response. I restarted my computer and opened my SSIS project without any other applications. Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Just an update, I do not know the other options, However, I split this project into several projects, and it works well, and these projects can be opened by Visual Studio.
